# multiple delimiters: split on first delimiter only if second is not found

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Trying to create a regular expression that will split a string on either pipe (|) or comma (,) only if the string does not contain the pipe character.

So i know this will split on both delimiters fine:

```
>>> s = '10,20|30|40'
>>> re.split(',|\|', s)

['10', '20', '30', '40']
```

but what i really want in this case is to only split on the pipe, so the results should be:

`['10,20', '30', '40']`

not exactly sure how to do this with regular expression.  i have tried something like this:

`re.split('[,![^(\|.*)]|\|]', s)`

but that just splits again by both delimiters.

Comment: that wouldnt work for say '10,20,30.40' though.   so the idea is have a one liner that can handle a string that may contain either comma or pipe as delimiters. if pipe exists, it takes precedence we should split only that character.   i know it's possible to do pretty easily with a conditional, but would be nice to have a one-liner

Comment: I think you mean "pipe (|) or comma (,) only if the string does not contain the pipe character"

Comment: @Nick yes sorry

Comment: W/o regex , `s.split("|") if s.find("|") >-1 else s.split(",") ` this will also work

Comment: yeah, i have something similar to that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use the python [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, you can use variable length lookarounds to split on a comma, only when there isn't a `|` in the string:

```py
import regex

strs = ['10,20|30|40', '10|20,30|40', '10,20,30', '10|20,30,40', '10|20|30']
for s in strs:
    print(regex.split(r'(?<!\|.*),(?!.*\|)|\|', s))
```

Output:

```
['10,20', '30', '40']
['10', '20,30', '40']
['10', '20', '30']
['10', '20,30,40']
['10', '20', '30']
```

Comment: thanks...i guess i was on the right track..minus the 'look around'

Comment: @mike01010 to be honest, I suspect your original code will perform just as well if not better than this.